# Interconnected and Communicating Programs

Tags: delphi, ipc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inter-process communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088776/inter-process-communication)

Using Delphi, is there any possibility that I build two simple programs that communicate and interact with each other, let's say by clicking a button in the first one the other one displays a message.

Is It Possible?

Comment: See [Cromis IPC and IMC](http://www.cromis.net/blog/2012/05/cromis-ipc-and-cromis-imc-updated/) for examples of using named pipes and tcp for interprocess communication.

Comment: The simplest solution is WM_COPYDATA

Comment: It would help if you could specify a little bit more what level of quality (QoS) you are looking in the communication. Things like: can you afford to loose messages, what should happen when one application is not up. Additionally, performance and scalability requirements and message type/payload (if any).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many possebilties for IPC

- Sending window messages
- using Named Pipes
- using TCP-IP / UDP
- shared memory

and so on ...

Easiest way would be sending Messages to a window handle found by FindWindow
Named Pipes and TCP-IP should be prefered for extensive communications.

Microdemo:

First Project:

```
unit Unit2; 

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TTMiniDemoSender = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  TMiniDemoSender: TTMiniDemoSender;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
Const
     C_MyMessage=WM_USER + 1234;



procedure TTMiniDemoSender.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 wnd:HWND;
begin
    wnd := FindWindow('TTMiniDemoReceiver',nil);
  if wnd<>0 then SendMessage(wnd,C_MyMessage,123,456);

end;

end.
```

Second Project:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs;

Const
     C_MyMessage=WM_USER + 1234;
type

  TTMiniDemoReceiver = class(TForm)
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
    Procedure MyMessage(var MSG:TMessage); message C_MyMessage;
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  TMiniDemoReceiver: TTMiniDemoReceiver;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TTMiniDemoReceiver }

procedure TTMiniDemoReceiver.MyMessage(var MSG: TMessage);
begin
   Showmessage(IntToStr(MSG.WParam) + '-' + IntToStr(MSG.LParam) );
   msg.Result := -1;
end;

end.
```

For transferring more information you could use [WM_CopyData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms649011%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: ,, please if you could provide more details on FindWindow and Tcp ,, i don't know what are those !!!!

Comment: TCP is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol

Comment: @bummy in windows TCP makes redundant memory copying. For extensive communication shared-mem based approach is slightly better

Comment: In fact shared mem is a nightmare of complexity. Message passing is far simpler.

Comment: Complexity may be implemented once and incapsulated, like interlocked TQueue or somthing. And yes, massively extensive communication might be complex. Messaging requires either broadcast with RegisterWindowsMessage or lazy FindWindow approach, which always leaves me in FUD: how many men named David Hefferman live in your country ? :-)

Comment: @Arioch who is David Heffer*m*an?

Comment: @David Oops, sorry :-) That's why WM_COPYDATA failed :-D

Comment: @Arioch'The Your preferred mechanism that allows one app to find another can also be used with `WM_COPYDATA`. I just don't see why you want to bring in performance issues here. Doesn't sound like performance is critical for Billo. Something simple that works is surely best.

Comment: @David that comment of copying was not to Billo but to Bummi, who referenced extensive communications

Comment: @Bummi - one more note, you'd better change `SendMessage` to `PostMessage` to avoid program freeze whether another program misbehaves

Comment: @Arioch'The in this case you are right, but it depends, sometimes you'll need the result of a message, in other cases it might be dangerous e.g. WM_CopyData.

Comment: In fact SendMessageTimeout is usually the correct approach.

Answer (score 1):

For applications running on different systems and other advances requirements, there are also messaging solutions like [Microsoft Message Queuing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Message_Queuing) (MSMQ) or cross-platform message brokers based solutions like the open source systems Apache [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/), HornetQ and RabbitMQ.

With these messaging systems, it is easy to implement reliable peer-to-peer communication which even works if the receiver is currently not listening.

There are Delphi / Free Pascal client libraries available, commercial and open source.