# Communication with two application on Windows with DELPHI

Tags: windows, delphi, communication

I have two applications and would like the two to communicate texting when a release exception.

The problem is as follows: 
in an application I use the function

```
Application.Handle
```

to grab the handle of the application.

And in my client I use:

```
ServerApplicationHandle: = FindWindow ('TForm1', 'Form1');
```

To know which application should I send the message, but both return different numbers, they would know tell me why?

Comment: [pipes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28software%29) are normaly the way to communicate between two or more applications.

Comment: See [Inter-process communication](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4090025/576719) for communication using pipes.

Comment: Memory mapped files are very fast too, and work between applications (on the same computer)

Comment: @mjn memory mapping is surely not the way to go. How do you signal that there's a new message? How do you synchronize?

Answer (score 2):

As already explained (Main)Form and Application are two different things.
Since Delphi 2007 there is another behavior to note.
In dependency of Application.MainformOnTaskbar you are able (or not) to get the handle via Findwindow.

A little snipplet to show the different behavior

```
var
  FW_ah, FW_mfh, ah, mfh: THandle;

  Procedure Display(OnTask: Boolean);
  begin
    Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := OnTask;
    ah := Application.Handle;
    mfh := MainForm.Handle;
    FW_ah := FindWindow(PChar(Application.ClassName), PChar(Application.Title));
    FW_mfh := FindWindow(PChar(ClassName), PChar(Caption));
    Showmessage(Format('ah: %d FW_ah: %d  -  mfh: %d FW_mfh: %d', [ah, FW_ah, mfh, FW_mfh]));
  end;

begin
  Display(true);
  Display(false);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

- `Application.Handle` is the window handle for the hidden window associated with the global `Application` object.
- `FindWindow('TForm1', 'Form1')` will return the window handle of a top-level form in your application.

These are indeed not the same thing. You could, I suppose, use `Form1.Handle` instead of `Application.Handle`. However, you would need to be wary of window re-creation.

Frankly this doesn't sound like the best way to do inter-process communication. Perhaps you might consider sockets or named pipes.

Comment: Thanks for advice, do you have an example? I will study the alternatives.

Comment: There are lots of examples around. I think I answered the question that you asked.