# Make Inno Setup Installer report its installation progress status to master installer

Tags: installation, progress-bar, inno-setup, ipc

I currently have two Inno Setup installers working around. I need one of them to report its status as a sub installer to another installer even it running with `VERYSILENT` command.

I need this to display a progress bar in my main installer according to sub installer's installation progress because I don't want any infinite (marquee) progress bars for this.

I also read about [IPC Mechanism in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088776/inter-process-communication). How can I add this communication abilities like pumps to Inno Setup source code? Any tips for starting?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not think you need to code fancy IPC stuff for this. Just exchange the information via a temporary file.

Child installer code:

```pascal
[Code]

function SetTimer(
  Wnd: LongWord; IDEvent, Elapse: LongWord; TimerFunc: LongWord): LongWord;
  external 'SetTimer@user32.dll stdcall';

var
  ProgressFileName: string;
  PrevProgress: Integer;

procedure ReportProgressProc(
  H: LongWord; Msg: LongWord; Event: LongWord; Time: LongWord);
var
  Progress: Integer;
begin
  try
    Progress :=
      (WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Position * 100) div WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Max;
    if PrevProgress <> Progress then
    begin
      if not SaveStringToFile(ProgressFileName, IntToStr(Progress), False) then
      begin
        Log(Format('Failed to save progress %d', [Progress]));
      end
        else
      begin
        Log(Format('Saved progress %d', [Progress]));
        PrevProgress := Progress;
      end;
    end;
  except
    Log('Exception saving progress');
  end;
end;  

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  { When run with /progress=<path> switch, will report progress to that file }
  ProgressFileName := ExpandConstant('{param:progress}');
  if ProgressFileName <> '' then
  begin
    Log(Format('Will write progress to: %s', [ProgressFileName]));
    PrevProgress := -1;
    SetTimer(0, 0, 250, CreateCallback(@ReportProgressProc));
  end;
end;
```

Master installer code:

```pascal
#define ChildInstaller "mysetup.exe"

[Files]
Source: {#ChildInstaller}; Flags: dontcopy

[Code]

function SetTimer(
  Wnd: LongWord; IDEvent, Elapse: LongWord; TimerFunc: LongWord): LongWord;
  external 'SetTimer@user32.dll stdcall';
function KillTimer(hWnd: LongWord; uIDEvent: LongWord): BOOL;
  external 'KillTimer@user32.dll stdcall';

var
  ProgressPage: TOutputProgressWizardPage;
  ProgressFileName: string;

procedure UpdateProgressProc(
  H: LongWord; Msg: LongWord; Event: LongWord; Time: LongWord);
var
  S: AnsiString;
  Progress: Integer;
begin
  try
    if not LoadStringFromFile(ProgressFileName, S) then
    begin
      Log(Format('Failed to read progress from file %s', [ProgressFileName]));
    end
      else
    begin
      Progress := StrToIntDef(S, -1);
      if (Progress < 0) or (Progress > 100) then
      begin
        Log(Format('Read invalid progress %s', [S]));
      end
        else
      begin
        Log(Format('Read progress %d', [Progress]));
        ProgressPage.SetProgress(Progress, 100);
      end;
    end;
  except
    Log('Exception updating progress');
  end;
end;

procedure InstallChild;
var
  ChildInstallerPath: string;
  ChildInstallerParams: string;
  Timer: LongWord;
  InstallError: string;
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  ExtractTemporaryFile('{#ChildInstaller}');
  
  ProgressPage := CreateOutputProgressPage('Running child installer', '');
  ProgressPage.SetProgress(0, 100);
  ProgressPage.Show;
  try
    Timer := SetTimer(0, 0, 250, CreateCallback(@UpdateProgressProc));

    ChildInstallerPath := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\{#ChildInstaller}');
    ProgressFileName := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\progress.txt');
    Log(Format('Expecting progress in %s', [ProgressFileName]));
    ChildInstallerParams :=
      Format('/verysilent /progress="%s"', [ProgressFileName]);
    if not Exec(ChildInstallerPath, ChildInstallerParams, '', SW_SHOW,
                ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
    begin
      InstallError := 'Cannot start child installer';
    end
      else
    if ResultCode <> 0 then
    begin
      InstallError :=
        Format('Child installer failed with code %d', [ResultCode]);
    end;
  finally
    { Clean up }
    KillTimer(0, Timer);
    ProgressPage.Hide;
    DeleteFile(ProgressFileName);
  end;

  if InstallError <> '' then
  begin 
    // RaiseException does not work properly,
    // while TOutputProgressWizardPage is shown
    RaiseException(InstallError);
  end;
end;
```

You can use the `InstallChild` like below, or on any other place of your installer process:

```pascal
function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;

  if CurPageID = wpReady then
  begin
    try
      InstallChild;
    except
      MsgBox(GetExceptionMessage, mbError, MB_OK);
      Result := False;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Another good solution would be to use the [`PrepareToInstall` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=PrepareToInstall). For an example see my answer to [Inno Setup torrent download implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41924722/850848).

---

*For [`CreateCallback` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createcallback), you need Inno Setup 6. If you are stuck with Inno Setup 5, you can use `WrapCallback` function from [InnoTools InnoCallback](http://www.sherlocksoftware.org/page.php?id=54) library.*

---

It might be better to use the `TFileStream` instead of the `LoadStringFromFile` and the `SaveStringToFile`. The `TFileStream` supports read sharing. With the `LoadStringFromFile` and the `SaveStringToFile`, the progress reporting may occasionally temporarily fail, if both sides happen to try to read and write at the same time.

See [Inno Setup LoadStringFromFile fails when file is open in another process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41058648/850848).

---

This shows how the child and master installer progresses are linked (if the child installer is not running with the `/verysilent` switch, but with the `/silent` only):

[image: Linked progress]

---

If you need to use a standalone progress bar, you can use the following master installer code:

```pascal
#define ChildInstaller "mysetup.exe"

[Files]
Source: {#ChildInstaller}; Flags: dontcopy

[Code]

function SetTimer(
  Wnd: LongWord; IDEvent, Elapse: LongWord; TimerFunc: LongWord): LongWord;
  external 'SetTimer@user32.dll stdcall';
function KillTimer(hWnd: LongWord; uIDEvent: LongWord): BOOL;
  external 'KillTimer@user32.dll stdcall';

var
  ProgressFileName: string;

procedure UpdateProgressProc(
  H: LongWord; Msg: LongWord; Event: LongWord; Time: LongWord);
var
  S: AnsiString;
  Progress: Integer;
begin
  try
    if not LoadStringFromFile(ProgressFileName, S) then
    begin
      Log(Format('Failed to read progress from file %s', [ProgressFileName]));
    end
      else
    begin
      Progress := StrToIntDef(S, -1);
      if (Progress < 0) or (Progress > 100) then
      begin
        Log(Format('Read invalid progress %s', [S]));
      end
        else
      begin
        Log(Format('Read progress %d', [Progress]));
        WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Position :=
          Progress * WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Max div 100;
      end;
    end;
  except
    Log('Exception updating progress');
  end;
end;

procedure InstallChild;
var
  ChildInstallerPath: string;
  ChildInstallerParams: string;
  Timer: LongWord;
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  ExtractTemporaryFile('{#ChildInstaller}');

  try
    Timer := SetTimer(0, 0, 250, CreateCallback(@UpdateProgressProc));

    ChildInstallerPath := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\{#ChildInstaller}');
    ProgressFileName := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\progress.txt');
    Log(Format('Expecting progress in %s', [ProgressFileName]));
    ChildInstallerParams :=
      Format('/verysilent /progress="%s"', [ProgressFileName]);
    if not Exec(ChildInstallerPath, ChildInstallerParams, '', SW_SHOW,
                ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
    begin
      MsgBox('Cannot start child installer', mbError, MB_OK);
    end
      else
    if ResultCode <> 0 then
    begin
      MsgBox(Format(
        'Child installer failed with code %d', [ResultCode]), mbError, MB_OK);
    end;
  finally
    { Clean up }
    KillTimer(0, Timer);
    DeleteFile(ProgressFileName);
  end;
end;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssInstall then
  begin
    InstallChild;
  end;
end;
```